# mongodb query using lookup field is returning the field value in an unexpected single element array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a query in mongo that looks like this

```
db.tbl.aggregate([

    {
        $match: {
            "afield": "abc"
        }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
        {
            "from": "tbl2",
            "localField": "typeId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "type"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            "typeId": 1,
            "timestamp": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            "_id": "$typeId",
            latestRecord: {
                $last: {
                    "typeName": "$type.name",
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ])
```

Basically `typeId` is an `_id` of another collection and I want to retrieve some information from this other collection, particularly a string field called `name.

My query works, however, in the result of this query, `typeName` is going to be an array of a single element of type string.

I've created [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/u__QF099UBq). Here the results are:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "ff",
    "latestRecord": {
      "typeName": [
        "type2"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "gg",
    "latestRecord": {
      "typeName": [
        "type1"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

whereas I would like them to be:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "ff",
    "latestRecord": {
      "typeName":
        "type2"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "gg",
    "latestRecord": {
      "typeName":
        "type1"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: You can use the `$arrayElemAt` operator on the `typeName` array field. - referring to your present output.

Answer (score 0):

Although I still don't know why it is putting the field inside an array, the solution from the comment is:

```
db.tbl.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      unitId: "abc"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      "from": "tbl2",
      "localField": "typeId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "type"
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      typeId: 1,
      timestamp: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$typeId",
      latestRecord: {
        $last: {
          "typeName": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
              "$type.name",
              0
            ]
          },
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```